# Can I share clipboard content between nested X servers?

Tags: clipboard, x-server

I'm using Xnest to run a nested X server inside my main X server.

But their clipboards (selections) are independent, so I cannot easily copy text from one to another. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352632/how-can-i-share-my-clipboard-between-two-x-servers), I'm using [xclip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) in this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
# copy from :0 to :1
xclip -selection clip -o -display :0 | xclip -selection clip -i -display :1
```

Swap `:0` with `:1` if you want to copy the other way around. This works for example in a browser with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem last week and all the options I could find were unsatisfactory: they either have annoying delays, or only sync in one direction, or wake up the CPU unnecessarily.  After some experimentation I made a script called xclipsync that solves the problem properly, even if you're syncing between multiple Xephyr/Xnest instances or screens.

https://github.com/apenwarr/xclipsync